# How to add params id in rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Job model that contains a Company_id as a foreign key. On the company show page, I want to use a link_to tag that links to the Job new page so I can create a new job with the company_id using simple_form.

```
<%= link_to "Create Job", new_company_job_path %>
```

I get this error "No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>"13"}, missing required keys: [:company_id]"
This is my nested route

```
  resources :companies do
   resources :jobs, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

From rails routes, this is the route to the job new page

```
         new_company_job GET    /companies/:company_id/jobs/new(.:format) jobs#new
```

This is the simple-form in the job_new page

```
  <%= simple_form_for (@job)  do |f| %> etc
```

I would like know how I can include the company_id in to the link_to tag in order to use simple_form in the job new_page to create a new job.

Comment: Your job depends on a company, so you need one and pass the id to load the path. What's in your view?, you need a way to pass the company_id.

Comment: what view? in the job new page, i just have a simple-form. In the company show page, I have                                                                
    <h1><%= @company.name %></h1>

<%= link_to "Create Job", new_company_job_path %>

Comment: So use `<%= link_to "Create Job", new_company_job_path(@company) %>`, that's your company, there Rails will take the id.

Comment: thanks , it works. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails routes can take arguments; if you ever want to explicitly pass a parameter to a route you can do so just like you would pass an argument to any other method:

```
<%= link_to "Create Job", new_company_job_path(company_id: @company.id) %>
```

*note: this assumes you have defined `@company` somewhere on this view.

In the case of general resource routes, Rails is smart enough to insert these params in the right place. It's worth noting though that if a param is not defined on the route in **routes.rb** Rails will tack on these passed parameters to the end of the route as query strings.

For example, if you have a route like

```
get 'landing_pages/page' => '#landing_pages#page'
```

and you called:

```
<%= link_to "Go to your landing page", landing_pages_page_path(brand: 'Apple') %>
```

The route will become `/landing_page/page?brand=Apple`

For further reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: It worked, thanks for the elaborate explanation. I appreciate it